# Retrieve mongodb array element using java

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

I have this in my db.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59424f41baaacf1f40815ae8"),
"first_name" : "Yazid",
"last_name" : "Amir",
"gender" : "Male",
"hobby" : ["Memanah", "Business", "Fusal", "Makan"]
}
```

Let say that I want to retrieve the "Business" from array hobby. So my code will be like this

```
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("customers");
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("first_name", "Yazid");

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(whereQuery).iterator();

try {
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document str = cursor.next();



    out.println(str.get("hobby.0")); // display specific field
}
} finally {
cursor.close();
}
```

However, the result is null.

Comment: Get the property which is actually `"hobby"` and then access the array like a normal Java List. MongoDB "Dot notation" does not apply to Java Objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `List<Document>` to store your array

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document str = cursor.next();

    List<Document> list = (List<Document>)str.get("hobby");

    out.println(list.get(0)); // display specific field
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)